# Strategy for using Git across multiple platforms

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

My organisation uses Git with BitBucket (company policy) for internal software development. We have a specific repository in BitBucket which is used by our internal dev team, and periodically we'd like to take particular milestone commits from this internal repository and make them publicly available as releases on GitHub (unfortunately we can't make the BitBucket repository publicly accessible, hence GitHub is required). I am looking for a recommended approach that would allow for the following to occur:

1. Allow us to periodically take a commit from our internal BitBucket repo and push this to GitHub as a public-facing release. We do not want to make every internal commit public-facing.
2. Allow us to selectively exclude directories/sub-directories in the internal repo from any public-facing releases on GitHub (not all parts of the internal development repo should make their way into the public domain).
3. Support for all commit histories/notes from the internal BitBucket repo to be retained/published on the Github repo as each public-facing release is made (ideally notes relating to excluded dirs/sub-dirs should also be excluded from any public releases).
4. If possible, support for any pull requests made on the public-facing Github repo to be merged into our internal development (i.e. BitBucket) repo.

There are likely several ways of achieving this style of development model. Is it possible to achieve this natively using Git and, if not, what other approaches would people recommend?

Answer (score 0):

A git commit is a complete snapshot of the state of every file in your repo, together with a commit message.  So there's no way to copy a commit itself while omitting files or part of the commit message.

It would be simple enough to write a one-page script that checks out a particular commit of your internal repo, copies over the files from that commit (excluding specified files or directories), and then commits it to your public-facing repo using the same commit message as in your internal repo.  Is there anything you need that isn't covered by that sort of workflow?